# Латынь или латинский?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Возник вопрос, как правильней - латынь или латинский (язык)? Понятно, что прилагательное от "латыни" не сделаешь: *латинская* буква, *латинский* алфавит, и т.д. Но когда речь идёт о самом языке (знать, говорить, изучать латынь/латинский), можно ли использовать оба слова?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: > Сегодня мы играем Первую симфонию до-минор, це-моль! Первую, потому
> что у него были и другие, хотя Первую он написал сперва... Це-моль -
> это до-минор, а до-минор - це-моль. Это я говорю, чтобы
> перевести вам с латыни на латинский язык Ираклий Андроников. Первый раз на эстраде (http://lib.ru/PROZA/ANDRONIKOW/r_perwyj.txt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Почти все словари дают к "латыни" помету разговорная, так что "правильней" будет "латинский", но некоторые термины (Вульгарная л., Средневековая л. и др.) я с "латинский" не встречал.

Comment: Верно.  И  разговорное  и  составная  устойчивых  словосочетаний.

Comment: Спасибо!!!